# How to change tick labels for plotly.graph_objects.Figure?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I have a figure that I create with:

```
import plotly.graph_objects.Figure as go

go.Figure(data)
```

Now, I want to change the tick labels using a custom defined lambda function, just like I would do it for a standard matplotlib figure like this:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter

formatter = FuncFormatter(*some lambda function*)
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticks(), rotation = 90)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
```

(In my particular use case, I have a matplotlib figure where my tick labels are integers that represent hours after a given start date, and I want to be able to convert them do strings in date format with my custom made lambda function)

How to do this? I have been googling for this functionallity for a long time now and found nothing that helps, while I really can't believe that there wouldn't be a simple, elegant solution for this.

Comment: https://plotly.com/python/tick-formatting/ This website should be able to help in what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I already read that page and it does nog provide the functionallity I need (defining a lambda like function that changes tick labels)

Comment: You could try and create a lambda function that appends into an empty list which is what you end up using for the ticks

Comment: Could you maybe eleborate on what you mean? Maybe write it in an answer? I have trouble understanding this and it could give you some rep ;)

Comment: Also, I dont want a function that just changes the 5 or so tick labels you see when plotting the figure. When zooming in (which is the reason I switched from matplotlib to plotpy), the tick labels need to adapt

Comment: For the zooming in, this should help: https://plotly.com/python/tick-formatting/#tickformatstops-to-customize-for-different-zoom-levels, and I will provide an example using the appended list in a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid it is a little difficult to directly apply lambda function to format plotly axis since the **tick label formatting rule uses d3 formatting mini-languages**.

I think one way is to create the ticks by yourself and mapping that via `Tickmode - Array`.